# Duck Typing with JSON object - try/except?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, error-handling, duck-typing

In AngularJS, I have a api request that goes out and a JSON is returned. The JSON is stored as object `data` and I use `data.Automation.Status` to check the string in `Status`.

There are a few JSON errors that could a rise(after http 200 success with the json returned successfully):

1. The entire JSON could be returned a blank string ""
2. data JSON object could exist, but Automation JSON object could be undefined
3. Property `Status` of object `Automation` could be undefined or a blank string

Coming from python, all these possible situations could easily be handled in a try/except block.

```
Try: 
  do something with JSON 
except (blah, blah)
  don't error out because JSON object is broken, but do this instead
```

I see angular has $errorHandler service that can be modified with custom handlers. But I am not sure if this can be used in the same manner of duck typing that I am looking for.

How could I go about duck typing in AngularJS? Specifically, for the JSON object error scenerios mentioned in the list above?

How I am using `data.Automation.Status` at the moment:

```
 if (iteration < Configuration.CHECK_ITERATIONS && data.Automation.Status !== "FAILED") {
    iteration++;
    return $timeout((function() {
      return newStatusEvent(eventId, url, deferred, iteration);
    }), Configuration.TIME_ITERATION);
  } else {
    err = data.Automation.StatusDescription;
    return deferred.reject(err);
  }
```

Comment: Not really related to the question, but I find the use of $timeout here really weird: shouldn't you use deferred.resolve() in stead?

Comment: You know you can do exactly the same in JavaScript, don't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way that comes to mind to handle this situation would be using $parse since it handles undefined very well. You could do something like this:

```
$http.get('/endpoint1').success(function(res) {
    try {
        // test response before proceeding
        if (angular.isUndefined($parse('Automation.Status')(res))) {
          throw 'Automation Status Failed!';
        }
    } catch (err) {
        // handle your error here
        console.error('Error in response from endpoint1: ' + err);
    }

    // if your assertions are correct you can continue your program
});
```

You can see in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/a0Y7ME?p=preview) how $parse handles your scenarios.

Comment: I like this since it seems the cleanest. Is there anyway I can give you the extra bounty points?

Comment: Not sure, I'm glad that my answer was useful though! :D

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I came to a solution for the same problem.
It keeps it minimal, and all of the tests are grouped in one block.

```
$http.get('/endpoint1').success(function(res) {
    try {
        // test response before proceeding
        if (JSON.stringify(res).length === 0) throw 'Empty JSON Response!';
        if (!res.hasOwnProperty('Automation')) throw 'Automation object is undefined!';
        if (!res.Automation.hasOwnProperty('Status') || res.Automation.Status !== 'SUCCESS')
            throw 'Automation Status Failed!';
    } catch (err) {
        // handle your error here
        console.error('Error in response from endpoint1: ' + err);
    }

    // if your assertions are correct you can continue your program
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how complicated you want to get. If you want to use coffeescript, there's a nice ? operator: `json.knownToExist.maybeExists?.maybeAlsoExists?()` will never error out, and will only call maybeAlsoExists if it exists.

Otherwise, you could use typeof checks:

```
foo = {a: 1, b: 2}
typeof foo === 'object'
typeof foo.bar === 'undefined'
```

I'm under the impression that try/catch blocks in javascript are relatively expensive. So you probably want to test the json manually, especially if the different return values from your service are what you'd call 'normal' responses. Exceptions, IMO, should be used for *exceptional* occurrences, and not sanity checking.